# How to use walrus operator in inline commands?

Tags: python

How to use (walrus operator `:=`) in inline commands?

instead of this:

```
>>> result = None
>>> if res := message.from_user:
>>>    result = res.id
>>> else:
>>>    result = message.chat.id
```

For example, can it be written in this way?

```
>>> ID = result.id if result := message.from_user else message.chat.id
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it possible?

I get an error when I use this mode
How do I write to avoid error?

Comment: @Prune `:=` is Python's "walrus operator", introduced in 3.8. OP, I'm not entirely sure what your code is supposed to accomplish, but encapsulating `w := x` with parentheses like `(w := x)` makes this a valid statement.

Comment: I know about the walrus operator, but ... never mind.  I misinterpreted the question.  I'll go away [blush].

Comment: I do not know of a way to utilize that variable since you do not have a scope within which to use it.  I do not think you can fit loop or code block within `a = '1' if (condition) else '2'`

Comment: `a = 4 if (w := x) else "No"` is syntactically valid. What do you expect (or want) the result to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The walrus operator has low precedence, so you need to parenthesize it to use it inside a conditional expression.

```
a = w if (w := x) else "No"
```